# How to set variable on onclick() function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown like this ->

[image: Screenshot]

```
<div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" id="Emp1" onclick="">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
      <img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'administrator/images/undraw_profile_1.svg' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="small text-gray-500">Johanthanc</div>
    <span class="font-weight-bold" id="employee1">Mr. Johanthan Cristofer</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" id="Emp2">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
      <img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'administrator/images/undraw_profile_1.svg' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="small text-gray-500">Johanthanc</div>
    <span class="font-weight-bold" id="employee2">Mr. Johanthan Cristofer</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on first div(for say div of id="Emp1"), name of employee should be set in a variable (i.e. div of id="employee1").

```
<script>

var employee;
jQuery(document).on("click", "#Emp1", function (event) {
  employee = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
  console.log(employee);
});
```

I want to pass the id of its nested division in the 3rd statement of script.
So, what should I write to assign a value in employee variable (3rd statement) -->
employee = jquery(this)....                   ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two classes:

- 1. `employee` for the element on which to attach the event handler
- 2. `fullname` for the element holding the wanted information (I assumed the full name here)

I also used [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to retreive an element from the event on another one.

I don't think you need to use some `id` for that purpose.

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", ".employee", function (event) {
  employee = jQuery(this).find(".fullname").text();
  console.log(employee);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center employee" id="Emp1">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
      <img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'administrator/images/undraw_profile_1.svg' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="small text-gray-500">Johanthanc</div>
    <span class="font-weight-bold fullname" id="employee1">Mr. Johanthan Cristofer</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center employee" id="Emp2">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
      <img class="rounded-circle" src="{% static 'administrator/images/undraw_profile_1.svg' %}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="small text-gray-500">John</div>
    <span class="font-weight-bold fullname" id="employee2">Mr. John Doh</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a class or an identifier to identify the elements.

You can just try

```
  <div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center user-menu-item" id="Emp1" onclick="">

// script
jQuery('.user-menu-item').click(function() {
  employee = jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''
})
```

or

```
  <div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" user-menu-item id="Emp1" onclick="">

// script
// in jQuery
jQuery('[user-menu-item]').click(function() {
  employee = jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the id this way.

```js
let employee = null;
jQuery(document).on("click", "#Emp1", function(event) {
  employee = $(this).find('span:first').attr("id");
  console.log(employee);
});
```